# Why is loop value never greater than 0?

Tags: c

I am trying to print out 26 children processes labeled A through Z with spacing set at `int wid = 2*(i-1)` for a cascading type effect. However, the value of i in the calculation is always 0 causing 0-1 to be -1 and then 2 * -1 to always be -2 for the width.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

    int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

        pid_t pid;
        int i;
        int j;

        for(i=0; i<26; i++){
            pid=fork();
            if(pid==0){
                int l;
                for(l=0; l<5; l++){
                    for(j=0; j<26; j++){
                        char value = j + 'A';
                        int wid = 2 *(i-1);
                        printf("wid: %d", wid);
                        printf("%*c\n", wid, value);
                        usleep(1000);
                    }
                }
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            while(wait(NULL)>0);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
```

I am not understanding how to structure the for loop to print out the spacing so i starts at 0 and goes to 25 causing the cascading effect.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this can be compiled because `wid` is used before its declaraton.

Comment: You called `exit()` after waiting your first child process to finish, so your loop won't go twice or more.

Comment: @MikeCAT Sorry, original had printf statement after declaration. Can you please elaborate more on the exit() problem? I need to call exit() at a different location to allow for the loop to go more than twice?

Comment: Does your "real" also miss to `#include` anything?

Comment: @alk (i-1) allows for a cascading effect of the letters.

Comment: But it would result in `-2` for for `wid` for the 1st iteration (`i=0`).

Comment: @Justin_Finland Get the second call of `exit()` out of the loop and move it after the loop.

Comment: @MikeCAT I updated with my understanding of moving exit(), but that update still causes i to be 0. Can you please explain your most recent suggestion and what I am doing incorrectly? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MikeCAT said in the comments, one problem is with the second `exit()` call.

Another problem seems to be one too many loops.

```
for(i=0; i<26; i++){
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0){
        int l;
        for(l=0; l<5; l++){
            for(j=0; j<26; j++){ // <-- Get rid of this line
                char value = j + 'A'; // <-- Use i instead of j
                int wid = 2 *(i-1);
                printf("wid: %d", wid);
                printf("%*c\n", wid, value);
                usleep(1000);
            } // <-- Also get rid of this line
        }
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  // <-- This is fine, exits the child process
    }
    while(wait(NULL)>0); // <-- Move with the line below
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // <-- Problem here, exits the parent process, preventing any looping
}
```

Since that is inside the primary `for` loop, it never has a chance to loop because it exits at the end of the first iteration. Move the problematic `exit()` below the `}` after it, and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: I printed out way too many values now because each letters should only be printed 5 times total so something is wrong with moving the exit().

Comment: @Justin_Finland Your `j` loop is iterating through each letter, printing them as it goes. Your `l` loop is causing the `j` loop to repeat 5 times. Your `i` loop is then causing all of that to repeat 26 times. In total you're printing each letter `5*26 = 130 times` (each child process is printing the alphabet 5 times). I suspect this particular problem is not with the `exit()`, but with how many loops you have, but you'll need to clarify what exactly you're looking for before I can say for sure.

Comment: I understand what you mean by the printing of each letter 130 times. However, I am not uncertain how to perform changes to get the loops to print right. I explained in an update about what I am trying to do. Also, when I maintain the exit() s in the fashion I originally had at the top of this post, the printing is correct expect that the spacing is not working. I explained above.

Comment: @Justin_Finland Ah, I think the solution for that is to get rid of the `j` loop. Move its body into the `l` loop, and use `i` instead of `j` to calculate the letter. Then each child process will only print out one letter five times, instead of the whole alphabet five times.

Comment: I am not sure that you understand fully. I want to print out the alphabet once than again then again then again then again. Thus, each letter appears five times, but not 5 times in a row. I implemented what I thought you were saying and will update now with the code and output.

Comment: @Justin_Finland I added a few comments in my answer that might help clarify what I was saying. With these changes, you will get the entire alphabet 5 times in total, instead of 5 times per process. **Note that you still need to move the second `exit()` call.** Since there are many processes involved, the order that the letters are printed will be effectively random.

Comment: I made your changes from how I understand them, and updated with the code and output. The cascading effect is working properly, but the order in which the letters are printed is not random, and the letters are not even at least printed one after another. I believe this suggests something is incorrect with the processes taking turns. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Note also that there is no guarantee that the letters are in contiguous order; for example, you cannot guarantee that 'I'+1 is equal to 'J'. this is especially true if the character set is EBCDIC where I is 201 and J is 209.

Comment: @Justin_Finland Oh, oops. That `wait()` is making sure that each child process finishes before the next is created, getting rid of that line (in addition to keeping the other changes) will *probably* make things print randomly (exact results may vary depending on when your operating system decides to schedule or preempt the processes).

Comment: @Justin_Finland On second thought, getting rid of the `wait()` line might be incorrect, feel free to try it, but if your program terminates too early, try moving that line outside the loop along with the `exit()` call.

Comment: I created a new question because the issue no longer pertains to the original question. I would greatly appreciate it if you could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to change this

```
   for(i=0; i<26; i++){
     ...
     while(wait(NULL)>0);
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

to become this

```
   for(i=0; i<26; i++){
     ...  
     while(wait(NULL)>0);
   }
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```